# Powerpoint Updating From Excel Data Gives 'File In Use' Alert Box

Tags: excel, powerpoint, updating

I am linking Excel data to a Powerpoint presentation.  The issue I'm having is that the file is in use.  How can I automatically tell Powerpoint to ignore this alert and just choose "Read-Only" to grab the new data.

Comment: Hi Rick, you should provide what you've done to solve the problem.  We help with code, your question is a bit too high-level.

Comment: I have done zero code.  I just used Paste Special --> Paste Link feature.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code after a quick search give it a try, I'm pretty sure that's your issue.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\myfilename.xlsx", , True)   'true here means readonly=yes.

objExcel.Application.Visible = True 'or False

objExcel.Application.Quit 'close excel
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

src: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/129741-vbs-to-open-excel-file-as-read-only